# Get data from 2 models with Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I need data from two models and would like to do it with one query. Here is what I have in sql that gives me exactly what I need. Can someone please show me how to do it in Django.

```
  select api_userprofile.last_name, api_userprofile.first_name, 
  api_userdevice.is_admin, 
  api_userdevice.is_alerts_enabled,api_userdevice.is_owner from 
  api_userprofile
  join api_userdevice on api_userdevice.user_id=api_userprofile.user_id
  where api_userdevice.user_id=10 and api_userdevice.device_id=29
```

These are my 2 models:

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    is_alerts_enabled = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    token = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to do in django what I did in my sql query above. I need first name and last name from userprofile and is_admin, is_owner and is_alerts_enabled from userdevice.

Comment: You could try something like this: https://chriskief.com/2015/01/12/combine-2-django-querysets-from-different-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is easy way to do that:

```
User.objects.filter(userdevice__id=29, id=10).values('userdevice__is_owner', 'userdevice__is_admin', 'userdevice__is_alerts_enabled', 'userprofile__first_name', 'userprofile__last_name')
```

Comment: Thank you, I also need to filter by device id though.

Comment: @robertwoods so add It in filter condition, answer updated

Comment: I wouldn't be asking in here if i knew how.

Comment: @robertwoods I updated answer. Check it. Filter condition by UserDevice as userdevice__id and User as id

Comment: Thank  you Jefferson!!